# I'm having trouble adding a column to a dataframe based on a function

Tags: r, dataframe

The problem is that the new column needs to have its values repeated a certain number of times. The data looks like the following, but repeats for hundreds of thousands of rows:

Dataframe: Ratings

```
 **USER#**  **ITEM#**    **Rating**

USER1     ITEM1 ....3

 USER1     ITEM2   ....2

 USER1     ITEM3   ....4

 USER2     ITEM1   ....1

 USER2     ITEM2   ....2

 USER2     ITEM3   ....5
```

I want to add a column that would have each user's mean average in each of their rows, so it would be like the following:

```
 **USER#**      **ITEM#**    **Rating**  **UserMean**

 USER1     ITEM1   ....3   ......    3

 USER1     ITEM2   ....2 ......       3

 USER1     ITEM3   ....4 ......      3

 USER2     ITEM1   ....1       ......2.67

 USER2     ITEM2   ....2  ......     2.67

 USER2     ITEM3   ....5     ......  2.67
```

I know how to get all the User Means using the following:

```
UserMean<-tapply(Ratings$Rating,list(Ratings$User),mean)
```

This gives each user's mean and I want for each row to show that user's mean rating, but it doesn't work when I use:

```
Ratings$UserMean<-UserMean # or the above tapply function
```

How could I achieve my goal? I know how to create an array showing how many times each user voted. Could I use that array somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are close, you just need the `ave()` function. Try

```
Ratings<-data.frame(
   User=rep(1:2, each=3),
   Item=rep(letters[1:3], 2),
   Rating=c(3,2,4,1,2,5)
)

UserMean <- ave(Ratings$Rating, Ratings$User, FUN=mean)
```

The `ave()` function will calculate values for each level you specify, and then preserve that value in the original order of your levels. It's basically like `tapply` in many cases, but it doesn't collapse values. It also can return different values for each level of the factor. For example

```
ReviewNum <- ave(Ratings$Rating, Ratings$User, FUN=seq_along)
```

which can track which review number it is for each user.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `ave` ( like mentioned in the other answer, I include my answer because I spent a lot of time to polish your data).

```
dat <- read.table(text='USER   ITEM    Rating
USER1     ITEM1 3
USER1     ITEM2   2
USER1     ITEM3   4
USER2     ITEM1   1
USER2     ITEM2   2
USER2     ITEM3   5',header=TRUE)

dat$UserMean <-  ave(dat$Rating,dat$USER)

USER  ITEM Rating UserMean
1 USER1 ITEM1      3 3.000000
2 USER1 ITEM2      2 3.000000
3 USER1 ITEM3      4 3.000000
4 USER2 ITEM1      1 2.666667
5 USER2 ITEM2      2 2.666667
6 USER2 ITEM3      5 2.666667
```

Another option is to use `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(dat,.(USER),transform,userMean= mean(Rating))
```

Answer (score 2):

`data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, UserMean := mean(Rating), by = USER]
dat
```

Or a less effective usage of base R functions than proposed above

```
merge(dat, aggregate(Rating ~ USER, dat, mean), by = "USER")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use dplyr:

```
require(dplyr)

Ratings <- Ratings %.% group_by(USER) %.% mutate(UserMean = mean(Rating))  

#   USER  ITEM Rating UserMean
#1 USER1 ITEM1      3 3.000000
#2 USER1 ITEM2      2 3.000000
#3 USER1 ITEM3      4 3.000000
#4 USER2 ITEM1      1 2.666667
#5 USER2 ITEM2      2 2.666667
#6 USER2 ITEM3      5 2.666667
```